# Gradle task assembleDebug failed error on running flutter app

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, flutter-web

Trying to run my app in my mobile phone error mentioned below. A simple login app and tried to run in web and successfully completed. I getting error

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

```
BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: This sometimes happens when there is an internet connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept the licenes from Android to run the app:

run: `flutter doctor --android-licenses`